# Java Http Tunneling

Tags: java, netty

I'm currently trying to implement a Http Tunnel between a Java Client(That Includes Netty) to a server, so I would like to know if there's any server that is also based on Netty to support this Tunnel or should I build the server side my self?

Comment: Why not implement the server-side on Netty too?

Answer (score 2):

I recently came upon this: http://www.jcraft.com/jhttptunnel/. Perhaps helps you...

Comment: This a regular low level IO, built on sockets... and it works only on the client side for now I'm building the client side on netty I need to start thinking about the server side...

Answer (score 1):

Now netty includes an [example](http://netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/tunnel/HttpTunnelingClientExample.html) of an HTTP Tunnel. The server must be aware (in some way) of it to work. The documentation of the API for HTTP tunneling (client and server) is available at [org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.http](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/http/package-summary.html)